# In SOAPUI service mocking, is there a way to generate representative values for response fields?

Tags: soap, soapui

I am trying to develop a SOAP client for a service to which I don't yet have access. I have therefore loaded the wsdl into soapui and am using the soapui service mocking functionality.

When I generate a mock response, the values are always set to '?'. Is there any way to ask soapui to generate representative test values given the type of each field? (The response in question has about 500 fields, so this would be really nice..). Alternatively, is there another tool I could use to generate such a response from a wsdl?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Ah - answered my own question. Go to preferences -> WSDL and check the box that say sample data for requests. Even though it says for requests, it also generates sample data for responses :-)